# Can I access the child model from the parent?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have created a productForArt and albomForArt model
From producForArt I inherit to albomForArt
Making a view based on generic.ListView
And I output it in the template,
Can I access the number Of Pages field in the template
albomForArt models, or in this case Django returns an object of the albomForArt model, but with properties that were inherited from albomForArt?

models

```
from django.db import models


class productForArt(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'товар'
        verbose_name_plural = u'товары'
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="цена", default=0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="название товара", null=True)
    description = models.CharField( max_length=1000,verbose_name="Описание товара", null=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey('typeProductForArt', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    def getType(self):
        return  self.type
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title) + ' по цене' + str(self.price) + ' шт'

class albomForArt(productForArt):
    numberOfPages = models.IntegerField(default=10,verbose_name="количество станиц" )


class typeProductForArt(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="none")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

vievs

```
from django.views import View, generic
from .models import productForArt

class startPage(generic.ListView):
    model = productForArt
    template_name = "startPage.html"
    context_object_name = "productForArt_list"
    queryset = productForArt.objects.all()[:20]
```

templates

```
{% if productForArt_list %}
    <section class="productsStartpage">
        {% for productForArt in object_list %}
        <article class="productForArtStartpage">
            <h1>{{productForArt.title}}</h1>
            <p>{{productForArt.description}}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </article>
        {% endfor %}
    </section>
{% else %}
    <p>товара нету</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [One-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

```
class albomForArt(productForArt):
   product_for_art = models.OneToOneField(productForArt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   numberOfPages = models.IntegerField(default=10,verbose_name="количество станиц" )
```

**Then in Template**

```
        {% if productForArt_list %}
<section class="productsStartpage">
    {% for productForArt in object_list %}
    <article class="productForArtStartpage">
        <h1>{{productForArt.product_for_art.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{productForArt.product_for_art.description}}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </article>
    {% endfor %}
</section> {% else %} <p>товара нету</p>{% endif %}
```